# Stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, database-cursor

Here I got a scenario: When I press a button in client application (developed in Delphi) a stored procedure is activated. The stored procedure first declares a cursor for a select statement which returns two columns-BankID and BankCategoryID.Then I need to fetch each row inside the cursor into a record and check for the BankCategoryID and return a resultset according to the BankCategoryID like:

```
CASE WHEN fetched_record.BankCategoryID=1  THEN
    SELECT STATEMENT1 WHEN fetched_record.BankCategoryID=2 THEN
    SELECT STATEMENT2 and so on...
```

and then I return the result set retrieved from any of the above cases to my client application. Is thi possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you'd want to use an `IF` as a control statement within your cursor?

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @BankCategoryID=1  
    BEGIN
       SELECT Baz From Bat;
       DECLARE @Spam bit; 
       SELECT @Spam = 0;
    END

    IF @BankCategoryID=2  
    BEGIN
       SELECT Foo FROM Bar;       
    END
  FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @BankID, @BankCategory
END
```

Here's a [sample TSQL cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-cursor-example-code.aspx). You'd be loading your two column values into 2 variables: `@BankID` and `@BankCategoryID`. i.e. `FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @BankID, @BankCategoryID`

Aside: I'm wondering if this could be done all without a cursor? In either case, the above should work for you in implementing more TSQL statements in each iteration of your cursor.

Comment: Is the "fetched_record." syntax true for MS SQL? It is  for Oracle, but I don't exactly know for MS SQL so I just wrote it that way.

Comment: @Mik: are you needing help constructing the TSQL cursor as well? If you update your question with the larger problem, I'll bet a cursor isn't needed. If you're game for it, update your question with more details.

Comment: Then how would I iterate through the result set without cursors?

Comment: @mik: Iterating through resultsets on the database server isn't a good solution. SQL is built for sets of data, and sometimes we programmers approach database problems procedurally, when a set-based solution is more performant and appropriate in the database. The vast majority of cases a cursor won't be necessary, depending on your goal. We'd want to leverage SQL's set-based paradigm so as to get the data quickly in one call.